# Installed package does not been used by system because existing package in different path

Tags: shell, homebrew, zsh

#### Situation

I am using **zsh** (oh-my-zsh).

**Homebrew** install all new packages at `/usr/local/bin/`, however, some packages are preinstalled on Mac OS, like `Git`, `Vim`, `emacs`.

When I installed the lastest version of these program using **Brew**, the newly installed program never get used becuase the existing one is located at `/usr/bin` which has a higher precedence.

My *current solution* is to manually delete the old version of program in `/usr/local/bin/` and then the newly installed program works.

#### Question

Is there a way to set the program installed using **Brew** execute first before the preinstalled program?

Providing suggestions and references on package control on Mac OS are greatly appreciated.

#### Answer

@tripleee provides a working solution below as an **accepted answer**.

NOTE: In case you do not have a `.zlogin` file you can create using

```
$ touch .zlogin
```

And then use your favoirte edito add the `PATH` into `.zlogin` file.

```
$ brew doctor
```

Can do the rest of the things for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your own personal `PATH` to your own heart's content.  A simple fix is to add

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to your `.bash_login`, `.zlogin` (for `zsh`) or similar.

Having a second copy of `/usr/local/bin` later in your `PATH` is by and large harmless, but if you like, you can fix it with

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH//:\/usr\/local\/bin:/:}
```

instead.  (If it comes last, you need to remove a pair of colons.)

Removing stuff from `/usr/bin` is **extremely** risky practice.  Don't do that.

Comment: i am using **zsh**, I do not have .bash_login. And I have removed `Git`, `Vim` and `Python` from `/usr/bin` what I should do now? Let me see if I can put `PATH` in `.zsh_login` or something similar.

Comment: Restore from backups or live with the inconvenience.  I imagine a future system update will bring them back sooner or later. In the meantime, only `python` seems like something the system might depend on in its daily operation.

Comment: The answer now mentions `.zlogin`.  See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html for a discussion of the various startup files and what they are used for.